# PjSip not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, pjsip

App is working fine prior to Marshmallow. Here is the logcat.

```
E/PjService: We have a problem with the current stack.... NOT YET Implemented
                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "BN_nist_mod_521" referenced by "/data/app/xx.xx-1/lib/arm/libsip.so"...
                                                       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
                                                       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                       at xx.xx.xx.PjSipService.tryToLoadStack(PjSipService.java:99)
                                                       at xx.xx.xx.SipService.loadStack(SipService.java:1050)
                                                       at xx.xx.xx.SipService.onStart(SipService.java:1011)
                                                       at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:459)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

AND

```
E/art: No implementation found for void org.pjsip.pjsua.pjsuaJNI.swig_module_init() (tried Java_org_pjsip_pjsua_pjsuaJNI_swig_1module_1init and Java_org_pjsip_pjsua_pjsuaJNI_swig_1module_1init__)
```

Can anyone guide me what to do?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you solved this problem?